# Go tour won't build on Mac

Tags: macos, go, offline

I installed Go on my Mac, no problem.  I'm going through the tour (https://tour.golang.org/welcome/3), which involves an example of local packages, downloaded packages, and automated tests, so it's reasonably good evidence that my installation is in order.  Then I see that there is an option to install the tour for offline use.  So, as instructed, I run "go get golang.org/x/tour" and get an explosion of errors, starting with:

```
# runtime/cgo
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
```

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm on 10.12.6 with xcode 9.2, and go 1.14.1. I just did `go get golang.org/x/tour` and it gave no errors.  Doing `tour` brings up the Go tour.  Maybe somehow double check that your xcode installation is OK?  Do you have an old xcode? I thought Apple stopped putting them in /Applications (or did they *start* putting them there?)

Answer (score 0):

From on the information you provided, I don't see you doing anything wrong. But it's not enough information to understand why you're seeing a problem.

Since you followed directions correctly, this might be a bug in the program, in the installation instructions, or something unusual in your environment.

I suggest filing an issue at [golang.org/issue/new](https://golang.org/issue/new?title=x%2Ftour%3A+) with "x/tour: " prefix and provide full answers to the questions it asks, so it can be investigated.